# Oracle 10g - Run a job that executes a batch file in local disk

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to run a .bat file after my stored procedure has done running. The purpose of the batch file is to create logs based on the code in the stored procedure. But I don't know how to run a .bat or even an exe file using PL/SQL Oracle.

Comment: Just another idea - can you write your stored procedure to write the logs instead? e.g. using UTL_FILE

Answer (score 0):

The oracle scheduler can execute OS programs (on the DB server), and you can create a scheduled jobs from pl/SQL.
Look at the documentation of DBMS_SCHEDULER package - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#i1000363